# Jquery Ajax POST method is not working, return undefined value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

POST method return **undefined value**, but GET method working fine. I even tried `$.post(url, data, success);` << `$.post` even worse GET and POST can't work.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit"  id="btnUpload">


$('#btnUpload').click(function(){       
$.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: { 'action': 'scan_email' },
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
        }
    });
```

ajax.php

```
<?php echo $_POST['action'];?>
```

Comment: what do you have on your form action?can you add html mark up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `method` instead of `type`:

**Code:**

```
<input type="submit" value="submit"  id="btnUpload">

$('#btnUpload').click(function(){       
    $.ajax({  
    method: 'POST',  
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: { 'action': 'scan_email' },
    success: function(response) {
       alert(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: It works. Why method instead of type? any different method, type, datatype?

Comment: Actually, `type` is an alias of `method` but it matters with jQuery version.

Comment: I see. I see all tutorials and stack overflow answer all almost are using type.

Answer (score 0):

Added the jquery library

```
<input type="button" value="submit" id="btnUpload">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('#btnUpload').on('click', function(){ 

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",  
                url: "login.php",  
                data: { 'action':'scan_email'},
                success: function(theResponse) {

                    // Output from ajax.php
                    alert(theResponse); // comment this

                    }  
            });
    });
});                 
</script>
```

Comment: I have added. otherwise it can't call php and return undefined value. Thanks sir.

Comment: yeah. Need to check the library version also, it matters with the events. Use 'on' instead 'click' which works better for dynamically added elements.